# What does "nothing was returned from render" mean?

Tags: reactjs

I write a short app for a refreshing in terms of time every second, but it does not work

```
function add() {
  const element = (

    <h1>
      hello, {formatName(user)}
        <h2>
          The time is {(new.Date().toLocaleTimeString())}
        </h2>
    </h1>

  );
  setInterval(add, 1000);
}

// Render function
function App() {
  return (
    add();
  );
}

export default App;
setInterval(App, 1000);
```

Here is the error I get :
App(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.

Comment: Hey Aedgen -- welcome to stackoverflow!  You generally shouldn't [link to images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) and instead directly include the code itself -- especially when it is this short.

Comment: Hello, I have updated my answer. Wanting to make sure that your problem has been solved.

Comment: Note: This is JavaScript, not Java. JavaScript and Java are two different languages, despite the similarity of their names.

Answer (score 1):

The App() function is returning the data that add() returns. Since the function add() only declares a const and then calls itself again, and no data is being returned, you will end up with nothing returned hence the error. If you add a return value to the end of that function (Im guessing that value would be the element variable), it should work.

I also noticed a runtime error can occur when you run your code since you begin with an interval that calls `App()` every second. `App()` then calls `add()` every second which calls itself every second. This creates `n` amount of intervals that exponentially increasing depending on the time the program has been running, eventually collapsing on itself.

To fix this depends on how you want this program to run, since you havent quite made it clear what youre trying to do. But if we assume that you simply want to run the function once every second, then deleting the `setInterval()` function in `add()` will solve that.

**Fixed code**

```
function add() {
  const element = (

    <h1>
      hello, {formatName(user)}
        <h2>
          The time is {(new.Date().toLocaleTimeString())}
        </h2>
    </h1>

  );
  // setInterval(add, 1000); Remove this to avoid runtime error
  return element; /* A return value is needed if 
  function App() itself is returning this function, that means
  whichever value this function returns is returned to App.
  If there is no return, then nothing is sent back,
  therefore "nothing" was returned from render */
}

// Render function
function App() {
  return (
    add();
  );
}

export default App;
setInterval(App, 1000);
```